# angularjs form validation syntax error token unexpected '{'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive to validate two form fields (dates) in angularjs (version 1.0.2). In order to validate the form I use the following directive. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/cafau/Ja2ar/
The only change I made is to rename the directive to ui-validate.
I have created a fiddle at 
    http://jsfiddle.net/sidkurias/xXf6b/
I have included part of the html I am using and relevant parts of the controller.
There are two methods on the controller validStartDate and startBeforeEnd that I would like to invoke from the directive. When I do so I get the following error

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 13 of the expression [(function (){
var sdate = new Date($scope.avail.sdate),
    today = new Date(getDefaultDates(0));
return sdate >= today ;
}) && true] starting at [{
var sdate = new Date($scope.avail.sdate),
    today = new Date(getDefaultDates(0));
return sdate >= today ;
}) && true].at Error (<anonymous>)
at throwError (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:5867:11)
at consume (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:5905:7)
at primary (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6075:7)
at unary (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6066:14)
at multiplicative (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6049:16)
at additive (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6040:16)
at relational (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6031:16)
at equality (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6022:16)
at logicalAND (http://g.dev/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6013:16) 
<form name="availForm" ui-validate="{startDate: validStartDate, sbe:startBeforeEnd}" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"> <br>
```

The call to the watch function resolves the validation functions correctly, but then it throws the above syntax error.
Any ideas as to why angular does not like the function definitions. 
Thank you

Comment: I don't see the directive code in your second fiddle.  Do you have a fiddle showing the problem?  The second fiddle also doesn't include AngularJS anywhere.

Comment: quite right, the second fiddle represents  just the partial that I pull in. This is a single page app - atleast, my attempt at one. I thought putting the entire setup into the fiddle would be too much. The partial is activated based on the route that gets triggered. I will add the relevant portions so that the problem can be reproduced, or I will create a simpler version so that the problem can be reproduced. Thank you

Comment: Finally figured jsfiddle.if you run the fiddle now, you can see the exception - at least in chrome console. http://jsfiddle.net/sidkurias/xXf6b/ Thank you

Comment: Just to add, I have changed the code a bit from my original application. For instance, I explicitly invoke the AvailabilityCtrl controller in the fiddle. The functionality has not changed and the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to place quotes ('') around your functions:

```
ui-validate="{startDate: 'validStartDate()', sbe:'startBeforeEnd()'}"
```

Comment: well that certainly did the trick!!! Being new to javascript, I can't tell why that is needed.Is this a javascript eccentricity or is it the way angular is processing the instruction?

Comment: It is the way this directive is implemented.

Comment: also did the work with ng-include="'/_lib/lib/my.html'", seems the underscore drove him crazy